# Go json schema generator

Tags: makefile

I have a big JSON object and need to generate type struct for the object.

I see this project and tried to use it.

https://github.com/a-h/generate

When I downloaded the code and ran the make command I get this error .

```
Makefile:34: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
```

Not sure how to fix it. I have opened a ticket and waiting for a response for now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go. You're probably using an incompatible version of Make. But in any case, if you want help, show your code (i.e. the broken makefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/). Just paste your JSON data in the left field and it will automatically generate structures with the appropriate tags.

If you really want to use [generate](https://github.com/a-h/generate) though, we are going to need to see the original JSON object and the generated structures to be able to help you.